# Why are self-programmed usercontrols with RadioButtons not synchronized?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have programmed for a WPF-application some UserControls.
One of these is a UserControl implementing the RadioButton.
This is the XAML of the UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UsercontrolExample.UserControls.ControlRadioButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UsercontrolExample.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="25"
             d:DesignWidth="150">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="border"
                Style="{StaticResource borderbasestyle}">
            <RadioButton x:Name="radiobutton"
                         Content="RadioButton"
                         Margin="2"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

In the cs-file i have programmed a property called "ControlIsChecked" for adjustment of the RadioButton's IsChecked property and in the constructor i set it to False, which should be the Standard for RadioButtons.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets if the checkbox is checked.
/// </summary>
public bool? ControlIsChecked
{
    get { return radiobutton.IsChecked; }
    set { radiobutton.IsChecked = value; }
}
```

On a WPF-window for testing the new usercontrols, i have placed two of my ControlRadioButtons on a Canvas, which lies on a GroupBox.

```
<GroupBox x:Name="groupbox1" Header="Selection" Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="152" Height="98" Width="157">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasgroupbox1">
        <Controls:ControlRadioButton x:Name="radiobutton1"
                                     ControlContent="RadioButton-1"
                                     ControlFontSize="12"
                                     ControlFontIsBold="True"
                                     ControlFontStyleIsItalic="True"
                                     ControlIsChecked="True"
                                     Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="10"/>
        <Controls:ControlRadioButton x:Name="radiobutton2"
                                     ControlContent="RadioButton-2"
                                     Canvas.Left="24" Canvas.Top="45"/>
    </Canvas>
</GroupBox>
```

Unfortunately my RadioButtons are not synchronized at runtime.
Normally when the first RadioButton is checked and i check the second, the first should be unchecked.
But in my case both are checked.

How can i synchronize the RadioButtons?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can derive ControlRadioButton from RadioButton (`ControlRadioButton: RadioButton`) to add new properties and override ControlRadioButton teplate (copy RadioButton template and edit it) *without* using inner RadioButton

Comment: But in that case i would have no Border anymore, isn't it?

Comment: by default no. fix is simple: in a new template make a Border around existing content

Comment: Meanwhile i have found out, that i can set the groupname property in the XAML of ControlRadioButton. But how can i get the parent's Name?

Comment: if ControlRadioButton is derived from RadioButton, you can bind inner RadioButton GroupName to parent ControlRadioButton GroupName. that would require to always set GroupName for ControlRadioButtons even if they are in the same panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the answers and inspirations.
Meanwhile i have found another provisoric way.
We are programming a dynamic WPF-application which Windows shall be generated by metadata saved in a DB.
By the way controls like our own RadioButton are always placed on a Canvas.
So i tried to find out the name of that ancestor and bound it to the groupname:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="radiobutton"
             GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}, Path=Name}"
             Margin="2">
    <TextBlock x:Name="textblock"
               Text="RadioButton"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"></TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```

By the time i will make a try with the proposal of ASh.